# Timer_fd python ? is there an equivalent

Tags: python, linux, asynchronous, epoll

I would like to know how to set a timer using python. I am currently using select.poll/epoll and creating a timerfd would have been the easiest method.

The other way i see it is after the loop check if any of my event passed time and execute their function.

Other method :

```
import select,time

timeout =0
epoll.register(rpm_file.fileno(), select.EPOLLPRI)

while True:
  events = epoll.poll(0)
  for fileno,event in events:
    #processing fd events...

  now = time.time()
  if now > timeout:
    # timeout events
```

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by "setting a timer"? Maybe your problem can be solved at a higher level.

Comment: i want to read a value from a file every 5 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer applies to Linux only.
You can try below python package called linuxfd, which includes a wrapper for timerfd:
https://github.com/FrankAbelbeck/linuxfd

It is indexed by python package indexes:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linuxfd/1.4.4

some example by the author:
https://abelbeck.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/more-on-linuxfd-an-example/